TransactionError: Can't acquire connection for the request. There is another request in progress
I am trying to insert data in two tables in SQL Server. The background is that I am requesting data of expenses invoices. Each invoice has one header and multiple detail objects. All connections and data formats are working right.
However, I am getting this error in NodeJS:

TransactionError: Can't acquire connection for the request. There is another request in progress.

(probably when trying to insert in detail table, ending up inserting in neither the header table which has preceded)
This is the complete controller of the request:
const mssql = require('mssql');
const dbconfig = require('../config/config');

exports.postexpensesall = async (req, res) => {
    let invoicesData = req.body;

    // Επεξεργασία πολλαπλών τιμολογίων
    if (!Array.isArray(invoicesData)) {
        invoicesData = [invoicesData];
    }

    let pool;
    let transaction;

    try {
        // Σύνδεση με τη βάση δεδομένων
        pool = await mssql.connect(dbconfig);
        transaction = new mssql.Transaction(pool);

        await transaction.begin();

        try {
            for (const dataToInsert of invoicesData) {
                // Εισαγωγή header
                const request = new mssql.Request(transaction);
                request.input('DocSeries', mssql.VarChar(50), dataToInsert.invoiceHeader.series)
                    .input('DocNumber', mssql.VarChar(50), dataToInsert.invoiceHeader.aa)
                    .input('CancelledByMark', mssql.BigInt, dataToInsert.cancelledByMark)
                    .input('AuthenticationCode', mssql.VarChar(250), dataToInsert.authenticationCode)
                    .input('IssueDate', mssql.Date, dataToInsert.invoiceHeader.issueDate)
                    .input('InvoiceType', mssql.VarChar(50), dataToInsert.invoiceHeader.invoiceType)
                    .input('VATPaymentSuspension', mssql.Bit, dataToInsert.invoiceHeader.vatPaymentSuspension)
                    .input('Currency', mssql.VarChar(10), dataToInsert.invoiceHeader.currency)
                    .input('ExchangeRate', mssql.Decimal(18, 5), dataToInsert.invoiceHeader.exchangeRate)
                    .input('SelfPricing', mssql.Bit, dataToInsert.invoiceHeader.selfPricing)
                    .input('AADE_UID', mssql.VarChar(250), dataToInsert.uid)
                    .input('AADE_MARK', mssql.BigInt, dataToInsert.mark)
                    .input('CounterpartVAT', mssql.VarChar(50), dataToInsert.issuer.vatNumber)
                    .input('MyDataPaymentType', mssql.VarChar(50), dataToInsert.paymentMethods.paymentMethodDetails.type)
                    .output('NewGUID', mssql.UniqueIdentifier);

                const result = await request.execute('dbo.ArrowAnalysisUpdate_MyDataHeader_Rest_API_EKS');
                const newGUID = result.output.NewGUID;

                // Έλεγχος αν το invoiceDetails είναι πίνακας
                if (!Array.isArray(dataToInsert.invoiceDetails)) {
                    dataToInsert.invoiceDetails = [dataToInsert.invoiceDetails];
                }

                // Εισαγωγή γραμμών τιμολογίου
                const detailRequests = dataToInsert.invoiceDetails.map((detail) => {
                    return async () => {
                        const detailRequest = new mssql.Request(transaction);
                        detailRequest.input('NewGUID', mssql.UniqueIdentifier, newGUID)  // Χρήση του ίδιου GUID
                            .input('LineNumber', mssql.Int, detail.lineNumber)
                            .input('Quantity', mssql.Decimal(18, 6), detail.quantity)
                            .input('NetValue', mssql.Decimal(18, 2), detail.netValue)
                            .input('VATCategory', mssql.VarChar(20), detail.vatCategory)
                            .input('VATAmount', mssql.Decimal(18, 2), detail.vatAmount)
                            .input('WithheldAmount', mssql.Decimal(18, 2), dataToInsert.invoiceSummary.totalWithheldAmount)
                            .input('StampDutyAmount', mssql.Decimal(18, 2), dataToInsert.invoiceSummary.totalStampDutyAmount)
                            .input('FeesAmount', mssql.Decimal(18, 2), dataToInsert.invoiceSummary.totalFeesAmount)
                            .input('OtherTaxesAmount', mssql.Decimal(18, 2), dataToInsert.invoiceSummary.totalOtherTaxesAmount)
                            .input('DeductionsAmount', mssql.Decimal(18, 2), dataToInsert.invoiceSummary.totalDeductionsAmount)
                            .input('CounterpartVAT', mssql.VarChar(20), dataToInsert.issuer.vatNumber);

                        await detailRequest.execute('dbo.ArrowAnalysisUpdate_MyDataDetails_Rest_API_EKS');
                    };
                });

                // Εκτέλεση όλων των αιτήσεων για τα detail
                await Promise.all(detailRequests.map(fn => fn()));
            }

            // Commit the transaction
            await transaction.commit();
            res.json({ response: "Expenses inserted successfully!" });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Transaction error: ', error);
            if (transaction) {
                try {
                    await transaction.rollback();
                } catch (rollbackError) {
                    console.error('Rollback error: ', rollbackError);
                }
            }
            res.status(500).send('Insert failed');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Database connection error: ', error);
        res.status(500).send('Database connection failed');
    } finally {
        // Close the pool
        if (pool) {
            try {
                await pool.close();
            } catch (closeError) {
                console.error('Error closing pool: ', closeError);
            }
        }
    }
};

